# Analyzing how noisy a data set using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data that has over 15,000 records in Excel that is from a measurement tool that finds trends over a large areas.  I'm not interested in looking for trends within the data as whole but rather over the data closest to each other to get a sense of how noisy (variation with neighboring records).  Almost like I want to know the average standard deviation of looking at the 15,000 or so records only at 20 records at a time.  The hope is the data values trend gradually rather than sudden changes from record to record and thus looks noisy.  If I add a Chart and use the "Moving Average" Trendline it kind of visually shows how noisy the data looks across the 15,000 + records.  However, I was hoping to get a numeric value to rate how noisy the data is vs. other datasets.  Any ideas on what I could do here with formula's built-in Excel or by adding some add-in?  Let me know if I need to explain this any better.

Answer (score 1):

Could you calculate your moving average for your 20 sample window, then use the difference between each point and the expected value to calculate a variance?

Hard to do tables here, but here is a sample of what I mean

```
Actual Measured Expected Variance
     5     5.44     4.49     0.91
     6     4.34     5.84     2.26
     7     8.45     7.07     1.90
     8     6.18     7.84     2.75
     9     8.89     9.10     0.04
    10    11.98    10.01     3.89
```

The "measured" values were determined as

```
measured = actual + (rand() - 0.5) * 4
```

The "expected" values were calculated from a moving average (the table was pulled from the middle of the data set).

The variance is simply the square of expected minus measured.

Then you could calculate an average variance as a summary statistic.

Answer (score 0):

Moving average is the correct, but you need a critical element - order. Do you date/time variable or a sequence number?

Use the `OFFSET` function to setup your window. If you want 20, your formula will look something like `AVERAGE(OFFSET(C15,-10,0,21))`. This is your moving average.

Relate that to `C15`, whether additive or multiplicative, you'll have your distance. All we need now is your tolerance.